# Prove parity function on n bits has circuit size O(nlogn), using AND, OR, NOT gates.

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, boolean-algebra

I was reading a book about computational learning theory, and it said that this should be easily provable. I don't know if it is because of my insufficient background in complexity but I am struggling to prove this.

If the parity function is simply f = $x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_3 \oplus... \oplus x_n$ , how do I prove this.

If i do a 2 input XOR, this is essentially a 5 gate circuit ($(\neg x_1 \wedge  x_2) \vee (x_1 \wedge \neg x_2)$). I read somewhere that NOT gates are actually not considered when taking considering circuit complexity, is this true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Xor is associative. First xor individual x, then for those pairs, then groups of 4, etc

Comment: @qwr Ah yeah of course. If one XOR gate is represented by essentially 5 gates of AND, OR, NOT, then n XOR gates are 5(n) basis gates. For an n bit parity check, we need n-1 XOR gates so 5(n-1) gates, which is grows slower than nlogn right? So 5(n-1) = O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XOR is associative:

We can actually use $O(n)$ logic gates by using XOR sequentially:
$$(\cdots(((x_1 \oplus x_2) \oplus x_3) \oplus x_4) \oplus \cdots$$

However if this is implemented naively as a circuit it takes $O(n)$ time since we need the value starting at $x_1$ to propagate.

It is much faster to use a binary tree structure:
$$(\cdots((x_1 \oplus x_2) \oplus (x_3 \oplus x_4)) \oplus \cdots$$

This takes only $n-1$ XOR gates if $n$ is a power of $2$, so it is also $O(n)$ logic gates, but uses $O(\log n)$ time.

I don't know what the $O(n \log n)$ logic gate solution is intended to be.

Comment: Actually what happens when you have an odd number of variables? Also, for n not being a power of 2, you must have n XOR gates, right?

Comment: If $n$ is not a power of 2, then the binary tree has ceiling of $\log_2 n$ layers. I think there still is $n-1$ gates, since every XOR gate takes 2 inputs and turns it into one output (subtracts 1 from the number of wires we have). These are all basic properties of binary trees